# Large-ish data storage for UITableView (Xcode 4)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Alrighty,

I am new to Xcode so I apologise if I am missing any key points here.

But, I want to have a large list in a UITableView type display. The list will be an array of strings with maybe 500 ish entries and a search bar to search for what ever entry you like. Once found you can tap the entry and it will load a detailed view of what ever it is. I would prefer to not have to have all of the data entry in Xcode and am wondering what would be the neatest way to store/read/write this?

I am leaning towards some sort of data file... but couldnt quite work out how to implement this into Xcode. I have searched around a bit but couldnt find anything which made sense (probably because i am quite new to Xcode).

This will be an App for iOS.

Any ideas?

Comment: I put an answer up, but as a hint, stackoverflow is generally a place for asking for help once you've run into a problem, not for getting advice on something like this. Try a bit of creative googling first and then ask us if you run into any more specific problems, we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to create a UITableView displaying static data and your problem is that you don't want to store the data in your code. Depending on how complicated the structure of your data is you could save it in a sql database, store it with coredata, keep it in a xml file or keep it in a file in a custom encoding. I don't quite now where your Problem lies. You can just load the file/database, parse it in an object structure and display it in the tableview. There are a couple of advantages of using a database to a file:

- You can create connections easily and handle them without a lot of effort
- You only need to load in the memory what is really needed at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Core data will be fine for you. However if you don't need all of its extra functions and the list will be static (eg, non changing and will be read into the code at runtime in its entirerty) then you can probably use a plist.  Plist data can be read directly into arrays.

Comment: Thank you heaps for the quick reply! and yes I will be more vigilant in my questioning now on...